# Unity5でOpenVRの初期化に失敗する

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity&プログラミング初心者です。
バージョンは5.5.1です。

Unity5でSteamVRとEditorVR使いたいのですが、エラーが出て、プレイボタンも押せません。

[image: Unity操作画面のスクリーンショット]

> - VR: OpenVR Error! OpenVR failed initialization with error code VRInitError_Init_PathRegistryNotFound: "Installation path could not be located (110)"!
> - Assets/EditorVR/Workspaces/Project/Scripts/AssetGridItem.cs(246,13): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Renderer' does not contain a definition for `motionVectors' and no extension method `motionVectors' of type `UnityEngine.Renderer' could be found.

スクリプトの画面を開くと、こう表示されています。

[image: 実際のプログラムのスクリーンショット]

```
    // Turn off expensive render settings
    foreach (var renderer in m_PreviewObjectTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        renderer.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off;
        renderer.receiveShadows = false;
        renderer.reflectionProbeUsage = UnityEngine.Rendering.ReflectionProbeUsage.Off;
        renderer.motionVectors = false;
    }
```

Unity、SteamVRダウンロード直後はエラーは出ておらず、
オブジェクト作成やカメラセッティングをしていく中で
気が付いたらエラー発生しておりました。

どう解決していけば良いでしょうか？

どうかご教授の程、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！できればエラーの内容は文章として（コピペで良いので）質問文の中に含めていただけると幸いです（ググラビリティのためです）。また、どういうことをしたらそのエラーが出たのかという状況も、より詳しく書いて頂けるとより良いと思います。ヘルプセンターの[「良い質問をするには？」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)もご参照ください。

Comment: Unityのバージョンを詳しく教えていただけませんか？　自分の質問は、質問の下の「編集」ボタンから自由に編集できます。

Comment: nekketsuu様　早速のご返信、本当にありがとうございます。頂いたアドバイスの通りに、自分の質問内容を編集させてい頂きました。右も左も分からないので、また何かご教授いただける事がありましたらお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

[Unityのドキュメント](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html)を確認してみましたが、Renderer.motionVectorsというプロパティはそもそも存在しないように思えます。

念のため5.3系と5.5系も確認しましたが同様に存在しませんでした。
どこかのサイトからコピペしたものの、そのコード自体が誤っている可能性が高いです。

下記の行をコメントアウトすれば良いと思います。

```
renderer.motionVectors = false;
// renderer.motionVectors = false;
```

Comment: どうも Unity 5.4 系のときだけ存在したプロパティのようですね……。 https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/540/ScriptReference/Renderer-motionVectors.html

Comment: 5.4だけ存在するプロパティだったのですね〜。おそらく参考にしたコードが5.4でしか動かないものだったのですね。

Answer (score 0):

Unityのバージョンが高すぎることが原因かもしれません。

[こちらのQ&A](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cannot-start-editorvr-missing-assembly-reference.446435/)によると、2017年1月現在EditorVRはUnity 5.5におけるAPI変更に追従していないようです。Unityのバージョンを下げるか、Q&Aにのっている[experimental Unity 5.4.3 Editor build](http://rebrand.ly/EditorVR-build)を使ってみてください。

Comment: nekketsuuu様　私の為に、わざわざ調べて頂いて本当にありがとうございます！頂いたアドバイスを基に、分からないなりにも、試行錯誤してみます！